# Why can't compiler find partial classes extending dbml?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a partial class called "trucks" which was automatically generated using LINQ to SQL designer. I extended the class using a partial class of the same name in a separate code file. I added a method called "ContainerCount" to my extender class. During development, the solution will sometimes build fine, but will sometimes come up with an error saying...

*CS1061: 'truck' does not contain a definition for 'ContainerCount' and no extension method 'ContainerCount' accepting a first argument of type 'truck' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

During development, all I had to do is build it again, and it would be without errors. It seems to be hit or miss. But now that I've uploaded it to the server, it shows the same error consistently.

Any ideas on why the compiler sometimes sees the rest of the partial class and sometimes doesn't?

```
//from DBML file
[Table(Name="dbo.truck")]
public partial class truck : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{...}

//from extension file
public partial class truck
{
    public int ContainerCount(CTSDataClassesDataContext db)
    {...}
}

//Code that creates error
int tContainers = 0;
foreach (var t in trucks)
{
    tContainers += t.ContainerCount(db);
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code, please?  Does the "trucks" generated from LINQ to SQL have 'partial' modifier?

Comment: Are the namespaces identical? Are the files in the same project?

Comment: I think it's due the DESIGNER stuff. It's kind of puting code into InitializeComponents() of windows forms. Somehow VS designer for different reasons decides to regenerate it, so your changes are cleared.  Think this is more or less same problem, as you're going to extend somethig that is generated by designer.

Comment: Because I'm using a separate partial class, my changes are not cleared, although they would be if they were in the same partial class.

Comment: @Tigran the whole point of partial classes is that you avoid that

Comment: The files are in the same web site. Like I said, the problem is hit or miss. It compiles just fine most of the time during development, but every once in a while it breaks. The only reason it's a problem now is because it's breaking consistently on the IIS server.

Comment: @Marc I know, But the only "strange" thing from NON edited post was that one....

Comment: Is this the only error you get, or are there other errors?

Comment: When doing a build in Visual Studio, I get other errors, all related to the missing partial class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when I do a build via "Build->Build Solution" after editing the dbml file, it tries to keep using an outdated dll. When I use "Build->Rebuild Solution" then it works fine. Looks like a bug keeps Visual Studio from seeing that the edited dbml needs to be rebuilt.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: +1: Not the first time I've seen something like this. I've run into a couple things where the `bin` and `obj` directories needed to be deleted (just in case) and then Rebuild done.